# How to switch iPhone views if password is correct

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller, passwords, uibutton, uitextfield

I have a screen that has a UITextField and a button. i got the code down to check if the password is correct, the only thing i need is some help to navigate screens. every tutorial i see uses XIB screens and i am using storyboard. Some help would be greatly appreciated. this is the code to check the textField:

```
-(IBAction)checkField:(id)sender{
NSString *pass = @"apc";
if([pass isEqualToString:password.text]){
    //Enter code to let storyboard know if its right or not?
}else{
    //Make a pop-up dialog(least of my worries right now!)
}
```

}

any help would be greatly appreciated. if you need to see more of my code to help just please ask !!!!!

Comment: I'd suggest presenting the password view modally so that you can just dismiss it and display normal views ordinarily (nav controller or tab controller).

Answer (score 1):

#### Preparation

1. Create a custom segue in your storyboard, which tells the code where to go. You can simply drag a segue by holding ctrl. Drag it from one view to another view, but don't drag it from a button or something. Use the views themselves.
2. Give the segue a name (identifier) by clicking it and giving it a name.

#### Execution

1. Simply call `[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"identifier" sender:self];`

And that's it :-)